# Python regex issue for findall function

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to come up with a regex to parse equation like 3x-5y+5, to split it in three parts.
Following is the code.

It works as expected for first three cases, 
but for last instead of -3y it gives just 3y

Why ?

'''

```
  import re
  pattern = r"[-+]?\d*\.?\d*[a-z]?"

  print(re.findall(pattern, "4y-3x-6"))
  print(re.findall(pattern, "4x+3y-6"))
  print(re.findall(pattern, "-4x+3y-6"))
  print(re.findall(pattern, "4x−3y-6"))
```

'''

output:

['4y', '-3x', '-6', '']

['4x', '+3y', '-6', '']

['-4x', '+3y', '-6', '']

['4x', '', '3y', '-6', '']

Comment: That's not a minus, it's a hyphen.

Comment: you can try: `r"[+-]?\w+"` as your expression. And nick is right - you have both hyphens and dashes in your text. so `r"[+-−]?\w+"` would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the string `4x−3y-6`. If you check for the hex codes of that string will you see that `−` is an hyphen and not the minus signal.

```
> echo -n '4x−3y-6' | xxd
00000000: 3478 e288 9233 792d 36                   4x...3y-6
```

As you can see, there are two different signals in there. If you want to use and match both, you should change your regex to:

```
  pattern = r"[-+−]?\d*\.?\d*[a-z]?"
```